# Configuration between Swagger, Spring Boot and OAuth 2.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, swagger, swagger-ui

In my API I am implementing Swagger 3.0 to document it at the same time I am implementing OAuth 2.0 for the authentication part, however, when running my program all endpoints are supposed to be protected by OAuth 2.0 and indeed they are, the The problem is that it does not allow me to authenticate and on the contrary it gives me the html of what is supposed to be the login that OAuth provides me.

[This is the POST method that is supposed to implement OAuth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92mYT.png)

[This is the answer I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xgzc.png)

[And this is the code I have in my SecurityConfig class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lDlL.png)

I appreciate the help you can give me. Thank you